# iOS - Getting Callback On Media Library Access Alert By System

Tags: ios

[image]

I need to reload the music list in my app when the user allows the access to media library, and I would like to show a notification when the user disallows the access. How can I get the two callbacks?

For requesting access, I just added this line into the info.plist `NSAppleMusicUsageDescription`

Comment: How are you requesting access?

Comment: @rmaddy I just added this into the info.plist NSAppleMusicUsageDescription

Comment: I'm asking what code you have that causes the alert to appear.

Comment: @rmaddy Sorry didn't get that. This one [[MPMediaQuery songsQuery] items]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ask for the permission for accessing MPMediaLibrary, this is how you can request for it

**Objective-C**

```
[MPMediaLibrary requestAuthorization:^(MPMediaLibraryAuthorizationStatus authorizationStatus) {
        if ( authorizationStatus == MPMediaLibraryAuthorizationStatusAuthorized ) {
        // Reload your list here
        } else {
        // user did not authorize
} }];
```

**Swift**

```
MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) in
        if status == .authorized {
            // Reload your list here
        } else {
            // user did not authorize
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `else` needs to check for "denied" and "restricted". Those two cases should be handled differently. Also note that the alert will only ever be showed once.

Comment: Hi, I just added that piece of code of yours in viewDidAppear. Then I inserted my code for reloading the list inside the if statement. However, it's not working, no alert were shown.

Comment: Delete the app and retry it, as previously you have added permission for your music library thats why it is not showing.

Comment: @Rajat If I allow access and then go to settings and disable it. How can I get system Alert to appear again?

Comment: @VyacheslavBakinkskiy if you have disable it, then there isn't any way to show the system alert again, you have to ask user to go thorough your app's setting and enable it again with proper UX. You can also redirect them to your app's setting.